# How to create application for mac?

Tags: c++, macos, installation, cross-platform

I created an application in visual studio 2008 using c++ and poco library. Since output of visual studio is .exe i have no idea how to create a mac application(.app file) with this. Can any one help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=how%20to%20write%20mac%20applications&safe=active&qscrl=1) can help:

- [How to get started with Mac Programming](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_to_get_started_mac_programming.html)
- [<strike>Writing Mac OS X Applications with Visual Studio Express</strike>](http://mac.sillydog.org/dev/visual_studio.php) - *Uses Mono*

Comment: The title of the second article is very misleading. Using Mono to make a .NET application run on a Mac doesn't magically turn it into a Mac application.

Comment: @Sherm Pendley: Fair enough, I'll remove that link.  However, if the OP is looking for a way to run their existing VC++ app in OSX, is that not a potential solution?

Comment: Yes, and it's not a bad solution, but the question the OP **actually asked** is "How to create application for Mac." Answers to completely different questions aren't really relevant here. :-)

Comment: @Sherm Pendley: The question title and the text in the question point to differing issues.  You're quoting the question title, but the text states that the OP has an existing Windows application that they wish to run on the Mac.  It's a matter of opinion I suppose, but without greater clarity in the question I'd say both links have some relevance.

Comment: Even the question text says "I have no idea how to create a Mac application (.app file) with this." Running a .NET application on a Mac is not creating a Mac application.

Comment: @Sherm Pendley: I'm sorry for not much specific to my question. But any suggestion to me will be helpful. Thank you for mentioning it.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you check out http://developer.apple.com
You may need to adapt some components, but I would recommend using Xcode.

Comment: Doesn't that involve having an actual Mac hardware?

Comment: No you can run Mac OS under a virtual machine.

Comment: I thought that was a license violation unless the host is also OS X, which was rather my point.